# Proper use of this->

Tags: java, c++, this

What is the proper use of the `this` self-reference of a class?

I sometimes use it inside a method to clear out that the variable used is a member variable and not one declared inside the method, but on the other side I am wondering if this is a good reason to do so, as I think you should always code (and comment) in a way which is self-explaining and therefore would make such an unneeded use of `this` unnecessary and another reason against it would be that you are actually producing more code than needed.

```
void function() {
  while(i != this->length) //length is member var
     /*do something*/
}
```

Another way of using it I frequently encounter is inside constructors (mostly in Java), as the parameters do have the same name as the member variables which has to be initialized. As the [Primer](http://www.amazon.de/C-Primer-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0201721481) states that this is bad code I am not doing this, but on the other side, I see how using the same name as the member-vars as parameter names clears out of which use they are.

```
C++
Constructor::Constructor(int size,int value) : this->size(size),
                                               this->value(value) {};

Java
Constructor(int size,int value) {
  this->size = size;
  this->value = value;
}
```

I hope there is actually a rule considering both languages (Java/c++), if not I will retag for just c++ as this is the one I am more interested in.

Comment: Another use of this is with respect to nested classes.  There can be more than one "this".

Comment: Java constructors of the style: this.a = a; are commonly accepted as correct

Comment: I know I have seen this question asked dozens of times before, some receiving excellent answers.

Comment: "What's the proper use of `this`?" In C++: if you have to ask, then not at all. (Perhaps with the exception of `std::bind`, or calls through PTMF.)

Comment: Personally, I like to see `this` so I can see at a glance the scope of a variable. But I come from a non-C++ background, so my practice is not necessarily best C++ practice. >.>

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan: Ex-PHP scripter? :-)

Comment: In C++, in the constructor case, the `this->` is optional. In the context of the initialization list, `size(size)` means *member-variable* `size` is initialized with *parameter* `size`, and is unambiguous (if maybe surprising at first)

Comment: @Kerrek Objective-C. Not the language so much as a stylistic choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the most part, `this->` is redundant.  The exception is if you have a parameter or a local variable of the same name (easily, and probably best avoided), or in a template, in order to force the following symbol to be dependent—in this latter use, it is often unavoidable.

Comment: Could you post a micro example of the template situation? I think that's very illuminating.

Comment: @KerrekSB: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299874/use-of-in-a-template-in-order-to-force-the-following-symbol-to-be-dependent) you go!

Comment: @KerrekSB `template <typename T> struct base { virtual void f() {}; }; template <typename T> struct derived : base<T> { void g() { this->f(); } };` is such an example, without the `this->` the `x` identifier is non-dependent and should not resolve to `base::x` (VS incorrectly allows this). You can manually force the resolution by qualifying with `base<T>::f()`, but that will also disable dynamic dispatch, so the only way of calling `f` polymorphically inside `derived` is with the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

`this` isn't necessary here as only members can be in init lists:

```
Constructor::Constructor(int size,int value) : size(size), // no need for this->
                                           value(value) {};
```

The only other use of `this->` is in templates.

```
template <class T>
struct foo : T {
  void bar() {
    this->x = 5; // T has a member named x
  }
};
```

If you don't have to use it then don't. Avoid having function parameters with the same name as members for things other than constructors and set methods.

Answer (score 1):

using `this->` explicitly states that you're referring to a member method/variable. Commenting to say this is just redundant... unless for some reason you have a local variable **AND** a member variable that have the same name and are manipulating them differently in the same code block, e.g.:

```
int x = 7;
this->x = 8; // yes, I really mean the member variable here
```

Comment: but wouldn't using the same name twice be already considered bad coding?

Comment: bad practice, but not bad coding. The compiler knows which variable you're talking about, because `x` and `this->x` are two completely different variables.

Comment: @Sim usually yes doing this is a sign of a bad name. However there are patterns eg Java constructors where this is considered normal.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this->` increases the length of your program, so it adds to the cognitive overhead of reading it. The only sensible use of it is when there is something in scope that shadows a member of the class and you want to access the member instead. Shadowing identifiers is a bad idea in most cases and there is a compiler switch in gcc (`-Wshadow`) that helps to avoid it.

Comment: *Using this-> increases the length of your program, so it adds to the cognitive overhead of reading it.* What? Can you explain that part?

Comment: Yes (maybe I didn't use the right word? English is not my first language). What I meant is that when someone (or even yourself) reads your program they will have to read and understand more code if you put this-> everywhere. Especially for a keyword that is highlighted, it occupies the thought process of understanding the code more compared to if it wasn't there. It's not significant for one instance, but it adds up. In other words, more code potentially leads to an increased [WTFs/min](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m).

Comment: +1 for the wtfs/min, never heard of it but loved it as soon as i saw

Answer (score 1):

The use of `this` in the constructor is not necessary: compilers are smart enough to tell parameter names from member names. The snippet below compiles and runs just fine:

```
Constructor::Constructor(int size,int value) : size(size), value(value) {};
```

In general, use of `this` for disambiguation is valid, but unnecessary: as you correctly noted, you can simply use different names for parameters and members, and that's that. However, there are cases when you must use `this`, otherwise things are not going to compile. Here is a somewhat contrived example - using `this` to set up a "back reference", as follows:

```
class Callback {
    Client *client;
public:
    Callback(Client* client) : client(client) {}
    // ...
}

class Client {
    Callback callback;
public:
    Client() : callback(this) {} // You must use 'this' here
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to name my variables in a way so that I see they are instance variables e.g. `m_foo`. I use only `this->` if the compiler requires me to due to some ambiguity because i find the code gets a bit difficult to read with expression that have lots of `this->` in them

Comment: IMO, m_ is just as smelly as this->