# Use of -> in a template in order to force the following symbol to be dependent

Tags: c++, templates

From the question:

[Proper use of this->](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8299674/propper-use-of-this)

The answer states that -> can be used

> ...in a template, in order to force the following symbol to be
>   dependent—in this latter use, it is often unavoidable.

What does this mean what what would a good example of this use be?  I don't quite what "dependent" means in this context, but it sounds like a useful trick.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Posted in other question:

```
template <class T>
struct foo : T {
  void bar() {
    x = 5;       // doesn't work
    this->x = 5; // works - T has a member named x
  }
};
```

Without `this->` compiler doesn't know `x` is a (inherited) member.

Similar to use of `typename` and `template` inside template code:

```
template <class T, class S>
struct foo : T {
  typedef T::ttype<S>; // doesn't work
  typedef typename T::template ttype<S> footype; // works
};
```

It's silly and somewhat unnecessary, but you still gotta do it.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer :) now to stop myself from posting another question on this one... typename T::template ttype<S> - why do you need ::template on this line?

Comment: @w00te There is an [excellent FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) that explains when and where to use `typename` and `template`

Comment: Thanks Praetorian - I'll check that out :)

Comment: @w00te It's using `template` as a qualifier. Without it the compiler would see the `<S` as less than S.

Comment: "_It's silly and somewhat unnecessary, but you still gotta do it._" It's absurd that `typedef` does not imply `typename`: there is no fundamental reason why `typename` is necessary just after `typedef`. OTOH, the fundamental need for `typename`, `template` and `this->` actually derive from the modern name binding rules of templates (see my answer).

Comment: @curious i showed in another question that c++ syntax is too flexible for that. for ex, `T typedef foo;` is perfectly valid. but there is no typename after `typedef`

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb What?!! This grammar is really awful.

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename T>
struct Base
{
  void foo() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Derived : Base<T>
{
  void bar()
  {
    // foo();  //foo() is a dependent name, should not call it like this
    // Base<T>::foo(); //This is valid, but prevents dynamic dispatch if foo is virtual
    this->foo(); //use of this-> forces foo to be evaluated as a dependent name
  }
};
```

A more detailed explanation is available on the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19)

Answer (score 0):

See [Using this keyword in destructor [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908248/using-this-keyword-in-destructor/7908530#7908530).

This is ugly, but this ugliness derives directly from the general name binding rules of "modern" templates (as opposed to macro-like template, as implemented by MS).